# PERFORMANCE: FASTER WAY for creating sub-dataframes for unique values of a column using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

**ISSUE:**
I need help with my below problem where I need to create sub-dataframe from a large dataframeframe for each unique value of ‘USER’ column and do some processing. This should be done very FAST, using multiprocessing to utilize all available CPU cores.

In this example I’m creating a dataframe with 1 million rows and 50 unique USERs.
But in actual scenarios the number of unique USERs is much more, sometimes more than 100,000. And, the number of rows sometimes are more.

Below is the source code, where I’m also creating the test daataframe (with 1M row). The size of csv file with test data is around 200MB.
Note: in my actual code this code (both calling code and called function are) is part of function(s) in NON_MAIN file, so I can’t use following code here `if __name__ == "__main__":`.
I’ve seen code at many places with ‘`if __name__ == "__main__":`’ code block, but I can’t use it because of above restriction.

Source Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import random


def dataframe_processing_by_column(dataframe, col_name, file_name):
    df = dataframe
    unique_col_value = df[col_name].unique()
    print(f"unique_col_value: {unique_col_value}")
    fh = open(file_name, "w")
    for i in range(0, len(unique_col_value)):
        df1 = df[df[col_name].values == unique_col_value[i]]
        print(f"----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value '{unique_col_value[i]}' at '{datetime.now()}'")
        fh.write("<Here the program logic will process the sub-dataframe --> append the output an output file. (this will be done for each iteration of the for loop)>")
    fh.close()

print(f"Starttime: {datetime.now()}")

user_list = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6', 'user7', 'user8', 'user9', 'user10', 'user11', 'user12', 'user13', 'user14', 'user15', 'user16', 'user17', 'user18', 'user19', 'user20', 'user21', 'user22', 'user23', 'user24', 'user25', 'user26', 'user27', 'user28', 'user29', 'user30', 'user31', 'user32', 'user33', 'user34', 'user35', 'user36', 'user37', 'user38', 'user39', 'user40', 'user41', 'user42', 'user43', 'user44', 'user45', 'user46', 'user47', 'user48', 'user49', 'user50']
url_list = ['https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/us','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/mumbai/bjp-is-ready-with-strategy-expects-new-government-by-sunday/articleshow/92504254.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/maharashtra-political-crisis-live-updates/liveblog/92502170.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/can-countries-afford-the-strings-that-come-with-an-imf-bailout/articleshow/92448842.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/mumbai/sc-order-paves-way-for-a-floor-test-say-experts/articleshow/92505381.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/open-to-considering-eknath-shinde-proposal-on-government-formation-bjp/articleshow/92504302.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/pawan-hans-chopper-with-9-on-board-crashed-off-mumbai-high-4-rescued-so-far/articleshow/92515004.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/dont-sabotage-your-investments-by-stopping-sips-now/articleshow/92450296.cms','https://www.gadgetsnow.com/us/news/top-5-monitors-in-the-us-worth-checking-out-for-2022-price-features-and-specs/articleshow/92414854.cms','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/ahmedabad/photos-from-gujarat-girl-who-lost-her-pet-dog-adopts-leopard-in-zoo/photostory/92513272.cms']
city_list = ['Delhi','Mumbai','Chennai','Kolkata','Hyderabad','Itanagar','Dispur','Patna','Raipur','Panaji','Gandhinagar','Chandigarh','Shimla','Ranchi','Bengaluru','Thiruvananthapuram','Bhopal','Imphal','Shillong','Aizawl','Kohima','Bhubaneswar','Jaipur','Gangtok','Agartala','Lucknow','Dehradun','Port Blair','Daman','Srinagar','Kavaratti','Leh','Pondicherry','Delhi','Mumbai','Chennai','Kolkata','Hyderabad','Itanagar','Dispur','Patna','Raipur','Panaji','Gandhinagar','Chandigarh','Shimla','Ranchi','Bengaluru','Thiruvananthapuram','Pune']
category1_list = ['Accounting', 'Advertising', 'Banking', 'Careers', 'Consumer Issues', 'Economics', 'Entrepreneurship', 'Equity','Franchising', 'Transport']
category2_list = ['Books', 'Celebrity', 'Entertainment', 'Movies', 'Music','Arts', 'Photography', 'Television', 'Reviews','Current Affairs']
category3_list = ['Brides', 'Caravans', 'Fashion', 'Food', 'Gardening','History', 'Homes', 'Magazine', 'Tourism', 'Religion']
category4_list = ['Motorbike', 'Netball', 'Rugby', 'Skateboarding', 'Soccer', 'Softball', 'Tennis', 'Architecture', 'Design', 'Cosmetics']
ip_list = ['172.217.24.11', '172.217.24.12', '172.217.24.13', '172.217.24.14', '172.217.24.15', '172.217.24.16', '172.217.24.17', '172.217.24.18', '172.217.24.19', '172.217.24.20']

data_file_path = "large_csv.csv"
out_file_path = "out1.csv"
out_file_lines = 1000000
column_headings = "USER,URL,CITY,CATEGORY1,CATEGORY2,CATEGORY3,CATEGORY4,IP\n"
fh = open(data_file_path, "w")
fh.write(column_headings)
for i in range (out_file_lines):
    res = f"{user_list[random.randint(0, 49)]},{url_list[random.randint(0, 9)]},{city_list[random.randint(0, 9)]},{category1_list[random.randint(0, 9)]},{category2_list[random.randint(0, 9)]},{category3_list[random.randint(0, 9)]},{category4_list[random.randint(0, 9)]},{ip_list[random.randint(0, 9)]}\n"
    fh.write(res)
fh.close()

df=pd.read_csv(data_file_path)

dataframe_processing_by_column(dataframe=df,col_name='USER', file_name=out_file_path)

print(f"Endtime: {datetime.now()}")
```

**Sample source dataframe:**

```
USER,URL,CITY,CATEGORY1,CATEGORY2,CATEGORY3,CATEGORY4,IP
user37,https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/pawan-hans-chopper-with-9-on-board-crashed-off-mumbai-high-4-rescued-so-far/articleshow/92515004.cms,Kolkata,Banking,Current Affairs,Homes,Cosmetics,172.217.24.16
user36,https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/maharashtra-political-crisis-live-updates/liveblog/92502170.cms,Delhi,Accounting,Movies,Brides,Skateboarding,172.217.24.11
user28,https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/maharashtra-political-crisis-live-updates/liveblog/92502170.cms,Panaji,Careers,Celebrity,Brides,Netball,172.217.24.18
user31,https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/ahmedabad/photos-from-gujarat-girl-who-lost-her-pet-dog-adopts-leopard-in-zoo/photostory/92513272.cms,Delhi,Equity,Current Affairs,Homes,Motorbike,172.217.24.16
user28,https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/us,Mumbai,Economics,Entertainment,Gardening,Cosmetics,172.217.24.11
```

**Output:**

```
Starttime: 2022-06-28 17:52:44.020216
unique_col_value: ['user49' 'user28' 'user23' 'user6' 'user21' 'user29' 'user41' 'user19'
 'user16' 'user32' 'user2' 'user5' 'user24' 'user40' 'user25' 'user37'
 'user1' 'user38' 'user26' 'user39' 'user3' 'user46' 'user7' 'user42'
 'user34' 'user14' 'user36' 'user17' 'user31' 'user20' 'user27' 'user9'
 'user45' 'user11' 'user10' 'user22' 'user8' 'user15' 'user30' 'user33'
 'user47' 'user44' 'user13' 'user43' 'user18' 'user50' 'user48' 'user12'
 'user4' 'user35']
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user49' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.389103'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user28' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.411150'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user23' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.432833'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user6' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.448414'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user21' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.469983'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user29' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.492125'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user41' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.513682'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user19' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.535357'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user16' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.557540'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user32' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.580355'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user2' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.597857'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user5' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.613739'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user24' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.636043'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user40' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.658612'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user25' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.680982'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user37' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.703319'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user1' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.719258'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user38' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.743347'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user26' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.764900'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user39' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.786943'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user3' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.805089'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user46' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.827766'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user7' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.845500'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user42' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.870025'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user34' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.895316'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user14' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.917818'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user36' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.941776'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user17' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.963017'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user31' at '2022-06-28 17:52:51.985831'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user20' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.008234'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user27' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.033975'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user9' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.051754'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user45' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.075136'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user11' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.098013'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user10' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.120366'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user22' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.141794'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user8' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.157748'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user15' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.179068'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user30' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.200452'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user33' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.224368'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user47' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.247848'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user44' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.271111'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user13' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.295599'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user43' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.317637'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user18' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.340106'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user50' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.358944'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user48' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.380731'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user12' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.402653'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user4' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.418713'
----sub dataframe created for unique_column_value 'user35' at '2022-06-28 17:52:52.440208'
Endtime: 2022-06-28 17:52:52.441582
```

If you carefully investigate the print statements, I’m printing the time at which the sub-dataframe creation is finished for each unique USER value.
Now, from output, the average time create each sub-dataframe is around 24 milli-seconds. If you consider 100,000 unique users it takes ~ 40 minutes. How can I reduce it?

**How can I make the whole code run FASTER?**
I see, in my 16-core CPU VM, python code is using only one CPU and that is used 100%.
How can I use all the 16-cores using multiprocessing and reduced the time?

Comment: There are some libraries wrapping `pandas` for using parallelism. I have heard about [Modin](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/speed-up-your-pandas-workflow-with-modin-9a61acff0076) and [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) to give you a couple. I hope those will work for you.

Comment: You are saying this should be done using multiprocessing, but have you actually tried using the `multiprocessing` module? You could create a pool of workers, where each pool gets the dataframe as input and creates the sub-dataframe based on one column.